# Sorting list of string with constraints of complexity

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

I need to sort a list of strings, where each string is of length `k`, and each string consists only of the characters `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'}`.
I do have the limitations of:

1. I cannot use any sorting methods include the methods that come with python.
2. Comparing 2 strings is of complexity `O(k)`.
3. Sorting is not in-place, a new sorted list needs to be returned.
4. Space complexity is `O(k)` [w/o considering the return list of length `n`].
5. Time complexity is `O(n*k*(5^k))`.

The function receives `lst, k` which are the list to sort and the length of each string in the list. I have 2 methods `string_to_int(), int_to_string()` that convert a string of length `k` to a number in the range `[0,5^k)` and vice-versa, the methods are bijections. Each of these methods are of time complexity of `O(k)`.

My best attempt was:

```
def sort_strings(lst, k):
  int_lst = []
  for item in lst:
      int_lst.append(string_to_int(item))
  sorted_lst = []
  for i in range(5**k):
      if i in int_lst:
          sorted_lst.append(int_to_string(k, i))

  return sorted_lst
```

But here I create `int_lst` which is of space complexity of `O(n)` and not `O(k)`.
Any hints of how to approach that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a *really* long time limit. That's enough time to go through every possible length-k string, in order, and compare those strings against every string in your input list.

What can you do with that?

Comment: So, iterating over all of the possible numbers in the range `[0, 5**k)`, for each iteration, iterating over `lst`, and comparing the int values of the strings in `lst`, each one that is equal to the current number will be appended to the list.That seems to work! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reuse `int_list` as the output, along the lines

```
    replace = 0

    for i in range(5 ** k):
        if i in int_list[replace:]:
            int_list[replace] = int_to_string(i, k)
            replace += 1

    return int_list
```

Edit: In case input list contains duplicates, consider `while i in int_list[replace:]:` instead of `if ....`.

Comment: I've thought about that already, but changing in place will get rid of duplicate strings, and it can reach the end of the range before converting all ints to string, thus returning a list with some sorted strings in the start, and the some ints which were not converted